# How to Prevent Inserting values to Database when refreshing the Jsp Page?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a jsp page  for inserting some values to database.Duplicate value is inserted to database table when refreshing the page.How to prevent this?

```
try { 
    //here all values are retrieve using request.getParameters 
    if(sage!=null) { age=Integer.parseInt(sage); } 
    if(contact!=null) { phone=Long.parseLong(contact); } 
    db.connect();
    int res=0; 
    String sql="insert into phr_login(name,address,age,phone,email,username,password,salt,category)values('"‌​+name+"','"+address+"',"+age+","+phone+",'"+emailId+"','"+userId+"','"+epassword+‌​"','"+salt+"','"+category+"')";
    if(name!=""&&userId!=""&&password!=""&&emailId!="") { 
        res=db.updateSQL(sql);
    } 
}
```

Comment: By storing the fact that you already inserted something for that call in session associated with the page?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: try
{
//here all values are retrieve using request.getParameters
if(sage!=null)
 {
  age=Integer.parseInt(sage);
 }
 if(contact!=null)
 {
  phone=Long.parseLong(contact);
 }
 db.connect();
 int res=0;
 String sql="insert  into phr_login(name,address,age,phone,email,username,password,salt,category)values('"+name+"','"+address+"',"+age+","+phone+",'"+emailId+"','"+userId+"','"+epassword+"','"+salt+"','"+category+"')";
 if(name!=""&&userId!=""&&password!=""&&emailId!="")
 {
  res=db.updateSQL(sql);
 }
  
 }

Comment: Are you resubmitting your from or just refreshing the page?

Comment: Seems like you're issuing a new POST, that would explain why the data is duplicated. Do you get a warning about resending the data when refreshing the page?.

Comment: @Templar,When refreshing the page

Comment: If you are resubmitting your form, then proper validation is to be done on the backend to prevent duplicate entries. If you are just refreshing the page, then there is no way the values will be submitted unless you are submitting the form on window.onload

Comment: how to submit form  on window.onload ?

Comment: in the servlet, before inserting,  check in db if any existing rows matches the  form data, else insert the record

Comment: You should read about SQL Injection: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: You should follow the post-redirect-get pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
response.sendRedirect("confirmpage.jsp");
```

And make a confirmation page to redirect to.  This is absolutely necessary.  You should never do a database update/insert without redirecting to another page afterwards.

To make sure your confirm page is accurate, you can store whatever info you need to display on it in the session and then read it from there.